# Best Approach for large MySQL database table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database table to hold attendance data per user per day. The table holds 2 rows of data per user per day and has about 10 columns. The data is grouped by a field called session_year. When I am analysing data it's always for a certain year. So I am wondering is it better for me to create new tables for each year? currently all the attendance data is in one table and hence the table has lots of data at the moment.

Question is will the amount of data in a table effect the query time of a table? So for example, if i'm querying data for 2017, will all the data for the previous years effect the performance of the query response time?

Comment: No, keep all data in one table. Make sure you have an index on the year, and you'll not suffer any noticeable performance-loss.

Comment: Its not very scalable to create a table for each year. What you should do is think about how you are going to query/insert the data and design the data model based on that. As you already know you will be querying based on year Id ensure that column had an index.

Comment: the real question is how many rows per year are we talking here?

Comment: @Jarek.D it varies year to year. can be between 200,000 and 400,000 per year

Comment: @trincot So shall I just index the year field? is there any point indexing any other fields?

Comment: That depends on the query. If you filter or order by other fields, then add those to the same index as subsequent index fields. Check the execution plan of your query (`explain`) to verify that the index is used (it should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question, yes the buildup of data from previous years would have an impact on query time, but if your indexes are correct then you wouldn't suffer any tangible performance hit unless we're talking millions of rows. Definitely don't split years into separate tables.

If however the amount of data is so large, you start feeling the pinch, you might consider [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html)